# Easiest way to find the mean of a dynamic array

Tags: delphi, dynamic-arrays

I have created a dynamic array, and have passed values to it. Is there a shortcut for finding mean of dynamic array.

```
var
  TheMin, TheMax: Integer;  
  x: array of Integer; //Dynamic array declaration
....
TheMin := MinIntValue(x);//I am able to retrieve the minium value of the dynamic array
TheMax := MaxIntValue(x);//I am able to retrieve the maximum value of the dynamic array
```

Is there a other way to get mean using Math library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very easy to write such a function.

```
function Mean(const Data: array of Integer): Double; overload;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0.0;
  for i := low(Data) to high(Data) do
    Result := Result + Data[i];
  Result := Result / Length(Data);
end;
```

I overloaded this so that it could sit alongside the same named functions in the `Math` unit.

If you wish to use built in library code you can use `SumInt` from the `Math` unit:

```
TheMean := SumInt(x) / Length(x);
```

`SumInt` performs the summation using an `Integer` accumulator. This is probably faster than the bespoke function that uses a floating point accumulator. However, an `Integer` accumulator is potentially subject to overflow which may be off-putting. On the other hand, an `Integer` accumulator is potentially more accurate than a floating point accumulator. Depending on your usage requirements these issues may be important to you.

In bother cases, if the input array is of length zero a runtime floating point divide by zero error will be raised.

Comment: I just took a look at Berlin's `SumInt`, and it does basically the same as you do, although it jumps through hoops (loop unrolling, etc.) to make things a little faster. It turns on overflow checks, even if they were off (and restores the previous state afterward). So the author must have considered this too. FWIW, not the fastest, but making a copy and then sorting the array might avoid an overflow that could otherwise happen. And it could also detect an overflow very early. After all, the result of Mean can not overflow, so it should be possible to do this without overflowing.

Answer (score 4):

If the array has additions or deletions, recalculating the average from scratch can get rather time consuming.

In that case it may be worthwhile to calculate a running average instead.

```
function RecalcAverage(OldAverage: double; const OldArray, Additions, Deletions: TIntArray): double; overload;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i:= Length(OldArray) + Length(Additions) - Length(Deletions);
  WeighingFactor := 1 / i;
  Result:= OldAverage;
  for i:= 0 to Length(Deletions) -1 do begin
    Result:= Result - (Deletions[i] * WeighingFactor);
  end;
  for i:= 0 to Length(Additions) -1 do begin
    Result:= Result + (Additions[i] * WeighingFactor);
  end;
end;
```

If you have a running sum handy, you can avoid the rounding errors and calculate an exact average.

```
function RecalcAverage(var RunningTotal: Int64; const OldArray, Additions, Deletions: TIntArray): double; overload;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to Length(Deletions) -1 do begin
    RunningTotal:= RunningTotal - Deletions[i];
  end;
  for i:= 0 to Length(Additions) -1 do begin
    RunningTotal:= RunningTotal + Additions[i];
  end;
  Result:= RunningTotal / (Length(OldArray) + Length(Additions) - Length(Deletions));
end;
```

If performance is an issue, it would make much more sense to calculate all the needed values in a single loop.

```
type
  TStats = record
    MaxVal: integer;
    MinVal: integer;
    Average: double; 
  end;

function CalcStats(const input: TIntArray): TStats;
var
  MinVal, MaxVal: integer;
  Total: Int64;
  i: integer;
begin
  Assert(Length(input) > 0);
  MinVal:= input[0];
  MaxVal:= MinVal;
  Total:= MinVal;
  for i:= 1 to Length(input) -1 do begin
    MinVal:= Min(MinVal, input[i]);
    MaxVal:= Max(MinVal, input[i]);
    Total:= Total + input[i];
  end;
  Result.MinVal:= MinVal;
  Result.MaxVal:= MaxVal;
  Result.Average:= Total / Length(input);
end;
```

Comment: A running sum would do, IMO.

Comment: Yes, but only if you have that running sum handy to begin with.